# Mediaplayer not playing audio from URL

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Currently I'm working on my simple media audio player on Android Studio, and I'm trying play a sound from URL, but I'm getting a error, check my code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initAudio(getApplicationContext(), "http://ntcdn.stream/audio/teste.ogg");
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

    }

    public void initAudio(final Context context, String url) {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(url));
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Falha ao iniciar o áudio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                killMediaPlayer();
            }
        }
    }


    public void killMediaPlayer() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want create a loop to play the audio always, but I got this error from logcat:

```
11-22 03:12:24.051 29582-29582/etes.giuseppe.databringer V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setParameter: key 1400
11-22 03:12:24.051 29582-29582/etes.giuseppe.databringer V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setParameter(1400)
11-22 03:12:24.051 29582-29582/etes.giuseppe.databringer V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAudioStreamType: 3
11-22 03:12:24.051 29582-29582/etes.giuseppe.databringer V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
11-22 03:12:24.051 29582-29582/etes.giuseppe.databringer V/MediaPlayer-JNI: set_session_id(): 8270
11-22 03:12:24.051 29582-29582/etes.giuseppe.databringer V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setAudioSessionId(8270)
11-22 03:12:24.051 29582-29582/etes.giuseppe.databringer W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://ntcdn.stream/audio/teste.ogg
11-22 03:12:24.051 29582-29582/etes.giuseppe.databringer D/RingtoneManager: Can't get current user. return default user
11-22 03:12:24.051 29582-29582/etes.giuseppe.databringer D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend : 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://ntcdn.stream/audio/teste.ogg
```

Can you help me? I really don't know what I should do to fix this problem.

Comment: Check if your url is correct and you're authorised to play it because the stack trace tells that the file was not found at that location.

Comment: The URL is correct, just check it by yourself at thread, and I've added all permissions at my manifest, still not working.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
private void startPlaying() {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(YOUR_URL);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```